# ObjectHandle unwrap gives me a MarshalbyRefObject object instead of my class object

Tags: c#, .net-assembly

I'm trying to load an assembly in to a an Appdomain and seems to get some problem with my ObjectHandle.

Assembly A just contains one class:

```
namespace MyTestAssembly
{
    using System; 

    public class SomeClass : MarshalByRefObject
    {
        public virtual bool Run()
        {
            return true; 
        }
}
```

And in Assembly B I try to invoke the class like this:

```
        var assembly_path = "/path/to/something.dll"
        System.AppDomain appDomain = System.AppDomain.CreateDomain("MyDomain");
        System.Runtime.Remoting.ObjectHandle oh = appDomain.CreateInstanceFrom(assembly_path, "MyTestAssembly.SomeClass");
        object obj = oh.Unwrap();
        obj.GetType().InvokeMember("Run", 
            System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
            Type.DefaultBinder, obj, null);
        AppDomain.Unload(appDomain);
```

This gives me the exception:

```
An exception of type 'System.MissingMethodException' occurred in    

mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Attempted to access a missing member.
```

And if I check the type of obj its a MarshalByRefObject when I expect it to be a "SomeClass" object. Did I miss something here? I have tried to look at examples and it seems like this is how most people do it.

Comment: It is a DLL Hell problem, the assembly you loaded is not the one you hoped to get.  Use Fuslogvw.exe to see how that happened.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. So I run the program but sadly I don't see the problem. I get a WhereRefBind log entry to my dll and inside that everything seems to be successful and location for ref-bind is correct (a bit unsure what to look for thought)